# Combine Multiple ls results Linux

Tags: linux, ls

I'm wondering if I can merge multiple ls results.

I have to combine 3 ls -l results; two directories have to list only directories in them, and the other lists symbolic links only.

The merged list'll finally be sorted by name or by date.

I did it by java code but I want to do it by single Linux command line if possible.

Thanks

Comment: thanks solved. Please answer my question, I want to choose you my answer.

Comment: That's great to hear! I anticipated so more back and forth for hidden requirements. I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better of doing this in find, but using `ls -l` to get out your file info for sorting by sort. Like:

```
 find /path/dir1 /path/dir2 /path/dir3 -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -l --full-time {} + | sort -k 6,7
```